# url matching regex for php

Tags: php, regex

I'm looking for a pattern that can match urls.

All of them will contain ".no" as there is only Norwegian domains input.

I think whats needed is this:

> search for a space or linebreak before and after '.no', and the match will be a link.

Some examples of what it should match (all with text around it):

```
test.no
test.no/blablabla/
test.no/blablabla/test.html
test.no/blablabla/test.php
test.no/blablabla/test.htm
```

and this should then be replaced with

```
<a href="http://www.MATCH">MATCH</a>
```

anyone can figure this out?

Comment: Have you tried [googling](http://www.google.ru/#q=URL+REGEX&oq=URL+REGEX) or [searching](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=URL+regex)?

Comment: yes but the examples i find all contains stuff like ".com" and just seem overly complex for what im needing here.

Comment: URLs are an incredibly complex thing. Check my answer and what (valid) [test URLs](http://daringfireball.net/misc/2010/07/url-matching-regex-test-data.text) Gruber specifies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
 $html = preg_replace("#\w+\.no[\w/.-]*#", '<a href="http://www.$0">$0</a>', $html);
```

Comment: hm that doesnt match `http://www.smykkmybitchup.no/halskjeder/sterling-silver/sterling-silver-halskjede-nr-23.html`
http://ideone.com/oiB6h

Comment: fixed (by adding a - to the end of the [] part)

Answer (score 0):

Check [John Gruber's Regular expression for URLs](http://daringfireball.net/2010/07/improved_regex_for_matching_urls) and go on from there.

Comment: seems all too complex for what i need. i mean, all i need to match is a string of characters which contains '.no' , and then stop the match at either a space or linebreak. the patterns in your link doesnt seem to match my 'test.no'.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is strict enough:
    ^[\w\d-\.\\]+.no.*$